# Knee deforming when applying armature to character

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I'm fairly new to Blender and rigging, and I'm having an issue.

After I'm done doing an armature for a character, making sure everything is aligned properly, I applied the armature via automatic weights - but when I go to pose mode after doing so, the right knee isn't set properly.

Like so:

https://webmshare.com/play/b8qXo

The only difference between them is the knife strap on the boot. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert myself, but I guess aligning both x normals to the outside should do the trick. [image]

Hope this works out.

Comment: How would I go on about doing that? The armature is mirrored so whatever changes I make to one knee also appear on the other.